# Display WordPress Posts in Static HTML page - Adding more details

Tags: wordpress

I need to add links to WordPress Posts on a static HTML page. I got some information that has been helpful but need a few more elements to make it complete.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
<?php

$number = 5;
$wordpress_header = "blog/wp-blog-header.php";

      // Include wordpress header   
      if (file_exists($wordpress_header))
       {
         include ($wordpress_header);

        $myposts = get_posts('numberposts=$number&offset=0&category=0');

        echo "<ul class='Bloglinks'>";

        foreach(array_slice($myposts, 0, $number) as $post) 
         {
            echo '<li><a href="';
            the_permalink();
            echo '">';
            the_date();
            echo " ";
            the_title();
            echo '</a></li>';
         }

         echo "</ul>";

       }
       else
       {
         echo "Unable to connect to Wordpress header file.";
         die();
       } 

?>
```

This only shows the titles of the most recent posts. I need to be able to display the following:

```
<h5>The truth about Lazy Eye</h5>
<p class="blog-info">07.16.10 | <a class="comment-ref">3 Comments</a></p>
<h5>More Adult Learning Problems Linked to Eyes</h5>
<p class="blog-info">06.12.10 | <a class="comment-ref">1 Comments</a></p>
<h5>New Vision Examination Instruments Arrived!</h5>
<p class="blog-info">05.10.10 | <a class="comment-ref">13 Comments</a></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the function [query_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/query_posts) with the functions have_posts() and the_post(). Here is an example for the WordPress API:

```
//The Query
query_posts('posts_per_page=5');

//The Loop
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
 ..
endwhile; else:
 ..
endif;

//Reset Query
wp_reset_query();
```

That will loop through all posts you have queried. So you can just insert your query from the get_posts() function into the query_posts() function.

**EDIT**: I think if you want to stick with the get_posts() function, you have to call the setup_postdata() function to get the new post ([source code for the API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts)):

```
<ul>
    <?php
        global $post;
        $myposts = get_posts('numberposts=5&offset=1&category=1');
        foreach($myposts as $post) :
            setup_postdata($post);
    ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

But I would recommend to take the query_posts() function instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php');
    $args = array(
        // 'cat' => 3, // Only source posts from a specific category
        'posts_per_page' => 6 // Specify how many posts you'd like to display
    );
    $latest_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $latest_posts->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $latest_posts->have_posts() ) {
        $latest_posts->the_post(); ?>
                                
                            <article class="vertical-item content-padding ls">
                                <div class="item-media">
                                    <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail() ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                                </div>
                                <div class="item-content">
                                    <h4 class="entry-title">
                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                                    </h4>
                                <div>
                                <div class="media-body media-middle greylinks">
                                    <br><a class="small-text" href="#"><?php the_time('l jS F, Y') ?></a>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item-footer">
                                    <a class="lato lightgrey weight-black" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read this Article</a>
                                </div>
                            </article>
        <? }
    } else {
        echo '<p>There are no posts available</p>';
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```